# docker php mongodb passing links to mongodb connection

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, php-7

I am trying to connect to mongodb from PHP 7.

I have nginx container, php-fpm container and mongodb container.

I installed mongodb driver using pecl and it is showing up in phpinfo(), mongodb ver. 1.2.3. Additionally I installed mongodb/mongodb using composer.

I linked my containers to mongodb (eg `--link mongodb_container:mongodb`)

Now when i am trying to:

```
$collection = (new Client('mongodb'))->streamflixmongodb->videos;
```

I would get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: 
Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb' in /vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:81 Stack trace: 
#0 /vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php(81): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->__construct('mongodb', Array, Array) 
#1 /var/www/html/test.php(24): MongoDB\Client->__construct('mongodb') 
#2 {main} thrown in /vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 81
```

Because connections should start with mongodb://

Additionally if I try to:

```
$collection = (new Client('mongodb://mongodb:27015'))->streamflixmongodb->videos;
```

I will get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: 
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): 
[connection timeout calling ismaster on 'mongodb:27015'] in
/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php:513 Stack trace: #0 
/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(513): 
MongoDB\Driver\Manager->selectServer(Object(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference))
#1 /var/www/html/test.php(27): MongoDB\Collection->find('.mp4') 
#2 {main} thrown in /vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php on line 513
```

The errors are generated when I run:

```
var_dump($collection->find());
```

What is the right way to pass links to new mongodb in PHP? Previously I used older mongo with php5 and it was fine.

my docker ps -a

```
93ce6947f2d8        vignatjevs/nginx        "/bin/sh -c 'servi..."   2 days ago          Up 57 seconds              0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32814->443/tcp         streamflix
569307612b50        vignatjevs/php-fpm      "/app-entrypoint.s..."   2 days ago          Up 2 minutes               9000/tcp                                             streamflix-php-fpm
03decea6dfa7        composer                "/docker-entrypoin..."   2 days ago          Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                                                        composer
c01b48fcdda3        jenkins                 "/bin/tini -- /usr..."   3 days ago          Up 21 hours                50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49001->8080/tcp                   clever_swartz
d16ace0397be        tutum/mongodb           "mongod --smallfiles"    6 days ago          Up 21 hours                0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:28017->28017/tcp   mongodb_streamflix
72e7bca2e2b7        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     12 days ago         Up 21 hours                0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                 streamflix_admin
a0988be5018a        centurylink/mysql       "/usr/local/bin/run"     12 days ago         Up 21 hours                0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6603->3306/tcp       streamflix-mysql-server
```

Comment: your `docker ps -a` says your mongodb container is `mongodb_streamflix` not `mongodb`, So, link your container to mongodb using ... `--link mongodb_streamflix:mongodb_streamflix`. and Inside your container, connect to mongodb using `$collection = (new Client('mongodb://mongodb_streamflix:27015'))->streamflixmon‌​godb->videos;` and let me know what happens.

Comment: Hi, sorry for me not clearing this up at the Firstplace. That link was just an example. My mongodb is linked using --link mongodb_streamflix:mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The problem was that i put SOME of my containers on the network, giving a parameter like `--network app-tier`

```
docker run -d --name streamflix-php-fpm --network app-tier -v 
/Volumes/Data/MSc\ Stuff/DEVOPS/streamflix-docker/php-fpm:/bitnami/php-fpm
-v /Volumes/Data/MSc\ Stuff/DEVOPS/streamflix-docker/streamflix:/var/www/html
--link streamflix-mysql-server:mysqldb 
--link mongodb_streamflix:mongodb 
--link videoserv:videoserver   vignatjevs/php-fpm
```

I can't believe i spent the most of the day because couldnt spot this :D

Obviously if I created network for some containers, I had to put them all on it, or remove `--network` paramater completely from anywhere to make it consistent.

Hope this helps somebody who gets stuck with the same problem.